# Blender: Export md2 animation of multiple objects (separate timelines)

Tags: animation, export, blender

I have 2 cubes in Blender and the timelines have to run parallely.

I'm importing to Android with min3d. But I guess the problem is only in the exporting part, so this should not be important.

Ok I'm using Blender 2.49 in order to export to md2 because could not get newer versions to run with that script.

Why md2, because it is the only animated format min3d can handle.

The problem:

md2 requires only 1 object, it doesn't seem to be able to export multiple objects.

So I joined (ctrl + j) my cubes. But then the animation is messed up. Timelines seem to be also merged and both objects move together the same way.

Any ideas...?

If there's a completly different way to get these animations in my Android project just tell me. But I don't have time to write an own exporter / parser so please don't suggest me that.

The only alternative I can think about, with my current knowledge, is export each object-part (each part which has an own timeline) as a separate object and the rebuild the "scene" (my object) in opengl.

Or export a static mesh and make the animation dynamically with OpenGL (which is what I'll do probably). Bit more work coding but is probably the easiest solution, for this case (very simple rotation + translation).

Answer (score 0):

If your animation is very basic (translation/scale/rotation) why are you merging them?
You can easily load them separately and then animate them with min3D in Java without OpenGL APIs.

Not to mention, min3D is little old and is not supported anymore. You may try [jPCT-AE](http://www.jpct.net/jpct-ae/) which is very easy to use and very handy to animate an object for simple animation. It is able to load MD2, 3Ds, OBJ and ASC models. jPCT has a better performance compared to mid3D (experienced).

For creating complex MD2 models which includes multiple meshes, I had the best experience with [Qtip](http://qtipplugin.com/) plugin for 3Ds max. It works like a charm.